# Animation example behaves erratically

Tags: javascript, multithreading, settimeout

I'm a beginner so I often use w3schools examples. They have the advantage of offering complete code, from html to /html. But this one failed.

I tried to use the example below to implement a game for young kids.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_animate_3

In my game, the user has to click on the correct location before the dropping object (a red square in this example) reaches the bottom.

Repeatedly clicking on the button produces erratic behaviour. At first the red square goes back up, but then sometimes it doesn't, and sometimes it reaches the bottom and bounces back up. If you click on it several times, quite fast, you will see what I mean.

I'm using Mozilla Firefox to test the game.

I think the problem comes from the fact that the code is interpreted in a non-linear fashion. I tried using while(1) with a break, I tried using global variables and testing each time before the move instruction as in :

```
if (finished == 1) return;
```

It's as if there was a thread somewhere who suddenly thought "Hey, I was moving this thing downwards. Let's send it up again halfway up the screen so I can finish bringing it down". And which does so even if "finish = 1".

I tried using timers as in :

```
setTimeout(function () {
  if (finished == 1) return;
  }, 100);
```

Nothing helped. I haven't tried to save the current state of the game in a bunch of cookies and to reload the page. Maybe I should do that, but isn't there a better way?

Comment: Maybe you could use something like lodash debounce method?

Comment: Which behavior on clicking again duriing the red square falls do you expect? It start falllig again or stops or anyting else? I can hlp with implementing your idea :)

Comment: Ezrab, thank you for the suggestion. I've had a look there : https://docs-lodash.com/v4/debounce/ but I don't understand it. I'm not even sure what language this is in. IMHO in javascript we never have to use "new" to declare a variable, or am I wrong?

Comment: PythonicSpeaker, I would like it to go back up and start falling again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made timer id global and clear it before starting again. In other words I stop the previous animation and start a new one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>

<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 

<div id ="container">
  <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>

<script>
var id = null;

function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```